# ReactJS Axios External API CORS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml, rest, cors

I'm using external API inside my React Project
But i got CORS Error there
When i'm googling, there are many article suggest to setup the CORS at the backend server
But in my case, i'm using external API which is i can't control their backend to add the CORS there
Can i disable it on the frontend or inside the browser only without touching the backend?
This is the Error code

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://externaldomain.com' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Comment: You cannot fix this on the client. If you don't own the API, proxy it through one you do.

Comment: How to proxy it?, or is there any chrome extensions for that? @jonrsharpe

Comment: I mean you make a request to your API and your server makes the request to the external API. And you can only use a Chrome extension if you can convince everyone who ever tries to use your app to install it.

Comment: i see, i think i would like to trying using the chrome extension, would you mind to tell me which extension shouldi use for this problem please? @jonrsharpe

Comment: I though I made it clear that was a bad idea, but if not: that's a bad idea. And recommendations are off topic on SO.

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/simple-node-js-proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the API is not configured with the correct CORS settings, and it is not your API, one of the solutions is to use a proxy that is configured to handle the request with the correct CORS headers.

It will look like this:

[image: cors diagram]

You can configure your own proxy or you can use a ready one like this (please note that the author of this proxy asks not to overuse is so if it is a big application you should set your own):

```
https://thingproxy.freeboard.io/fetch/https://externaldomain.com
```

Comment: it's work exactly like what i want, btw is there a limit for using thingproxy or what should i notice when i using thingproxy?

Comment: The author of the proxy asked not to overuse it. If you need something with a lot of traffic you should make your own proxy